# How to automatically import csv file(from local pc) every minute (synchronize it with my computer clock)

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a csv file in my computer that updates automatically after every 1 minute eg. after 08:01(it updates), after 08:02(it updates) etc...

importing this file to python is easy...

```
import pandas as pd
myfile=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\levels.csv')
```

i want to update/re-import this file after every minute based on my pc clock/time. i want to use 'threading' since i want to run other cells while the import function is running at all times.

so basically the code might be(other suggestions are welcome):

```
import pandas as pd
import threading
import datetime
import time

# code to import the csv file based on pc clock automatically after every 
  minute.
```

i want this to run in a way that i can still run other functions in other cells(i tried using "schedule" but i cant run other functions after that since it shows the asterisk symbol(*))

meaning if i run on another cell the variable 'myfile'

```
myfile
```

it shows a dataframe with updated values each time.

Comment: you say "cell" - do you run it in jupyter notebook, jupyter lab or Google Colab ? It may need different method then running in normal script.

Comment: @furas i run it in a jupyter notebook... i'm still learning

Comment: add this information in question because it make difference. notebook was created to run manually cell by cell. If you even run code automatically in one cell then other cells will not run automatically to update theirs values. You would have to run all code which use new data.